# Insert query result to table (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql

This Query:

```
ALTER TABLE planet_osm_line ADD vertices FLOAT;
INSERT INTO planet_osm_line(vertices)
SELECT st_NPoints(way) FROM planet_osm_line;
```

does result in a empty column (NULL). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE planet_osm_line ADD COLUMN vertices INTEGER;
```

Why float? Are there fractional vertices?

You are also inserting records, when I think you actually want to update each way with the number of vertices within. Use an update function to add the values to the new column based on the result of the function operating on the spatial column. For example, try:

```
UPDATE planet_osm_line 
SET vertices = ST_NPoints(way) 
WHERE NOT ST_IsEmpty(way);
```

Comment: Great, it's  working! The update function is the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [PostgreSQL Data Types Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html) it seems that there is no FLOAT data type. Try using numeric instead.

```
ALTER TABLE planet_osm_line ADD vertices numeric;
INSERT INTO planet_osm_line(vertices)
SELECT st_NPoints(way) FROM planet_osm_line;
```

Comment: "float" is an alias for "double precision" in PostgreSQL.